# How to create an absolute sidebar menu considering container height on bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a sidebar menu on my webpage with bootstrap 4, im not able to center content inside the list and display it only in the container, not in front or behind from footer, any help with this?

Or Is there something to create popups menu in the left or right from elements on bootstrap?

Desired result:
[image]

```css
.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.icon-box {
  margin-top: 8%;
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.icon-list {
  padding:0px;
  list-style: none;
}
.icon-list li {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-5">
   <div class="col-12">
    <h1>webpage title</h1>
    <p>Some webpage description</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row my-5">
   <div class="col-12">
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam interdum luctus diam, sed volutpat est vestibulum et. Sed libero turpis, accumsan vitae sollicitudin eu, blandit et erat. Integer in pretium libero, in lacinia diam. Curabitur ut eros feugiat dolor lacinia aliquet vel eu dui. Nam sollicitudin tempus mauris, cursus dignissim enim cursus eget. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas dolor risus, scelerisque at odio non, euismod semper orci. Sed consectetur libero elit, sed maximus arcu dignissim sit amet. Duis elementum diam molestie, venenatis est ut, sodales elit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse tincidunt ante at lacinia fermentum. Quisque tincidunt pharetra lectus, et sodales risus tempor vel. Aliquam erat ex, posuere in tortor sit amet, fermentum blandit velit.
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2 icon-box">
    <ul class="icon-list">
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12" style="height: 50vw; background-color: #00ffff2e;">
    <!-- here goes an svg map -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12" style="background-color: black; height: 120px;">
    <p style="color: white;">webpage footer</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I just use bs-4 classes to make `.icon-box` `position: absolute` and also make parent container `position: relative` and remove the `margin-top` of your side bar and set `top` and `bottom` values to `0`.

for more understanding show the below snippet:

```css
.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.icon-box {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.icon-list {
  padding:0px;
  list-style: none;
}
.icon-list li {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-5">
   <div class="col-12">
    <h1>webpage title</h1>
    <p>Some webpage description</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row my-5">
   <div class="col-12">
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam interdum luctus diam, sed volutpat est vestibulum et. Sed libero turpis, accumsan vitae sollicitudin eu, blandit et erat. Integer in pretium libero, in lacinia diam. Curabitur ut eros feugiat dolor lacinia aliquet vel eu dui. Nam sollicitudin tempus mauris, cursus dignissim enim cursus eget. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas dolor risus, scelerisque at odio non, euismod semper orci. Sed consectetur libero elit, sed maximus arcu dignissim sit amet. Duis elementum diam molestie, venenatis est ut, sodales elit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse tincidunt ante at lacinia fermentum. Quisque tincidunt pharetra lectus, et sodales risus tempor vel. Aliquam erat ex, posuere in tortor sit amet, fermentum blandit velit.
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid position-relative">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-2 icon-box position-absolute">
    <ul class="icon-list">
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
     <li><div class="mx-auto icon"></div></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12" style="height: 50vw; background-color: #00ffff2e;">
    <!-- here goes an svg map -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12" style="background-color: black; height: 120px;">
    <p style="color: white;">webpage footer</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this will works fine for you.

Thank you...